# FOSRestBundle no key-value in JSON

Tags: json, symfony, key-value-coding, fosrestbundle

I've set up FOSRestBundle with my small Symfony2 website. I've created some small GET methods and when I visit the api url, I get my JSON data. Perfect. 
But I'm trying to build an iphone app and I use RestKit for mapping/parsing json/... The problem I'm experiencing is that **it has to be Key-value coding (KVC) JSON data**.

I use this basic code in my ApiController to retrieve all data from my Sports database table:

```
public function getSportsAction() {
    $sports = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('MatchTrackerAppBundle:Sports')
            ->findAll();

    $view = View::create()
            ->setStatusCode(200)
            ->setData($sports);

    return $this->get('fos_rest.view_handler')->handle($view);
}
```

At the moment **I get this output**:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Voetbal"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Tennis"
    }
]
```

It doesn't have a key! How can I add a key in front of it. **What I want is**:

```
{
    "sports": [
    {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Voetbal"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Tennis"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is this possible with FOSRestBundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shot in the dark, as I've never used this bundle... but would this work?

```
$view = View::create()
        ->setStatusCode(200)
        ->setData(  array("sports" => $sports)  );
```

Comment: This works! Excellent. Had a feeling that it would be something easy, but all the Code & json samples on FosRestBundle don't use key-value coding, so I was clueless. Thanks